# Clarifai API not detecting the image URL in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, clarifai

I am using Clarifai API face detection and it is unable to fetch the URL which is provided from the constructor, rather than a variable which Clarifai provides in the default code

```
    class App extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      input : '',
      IMAGE_URL: '',
    }
  }
  onInputChange = (event) =>{
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  onSubmit = () =>{
    this.setState({IMAGE_URL : this.state.input});
    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      "user_app_id": {
          "user_id": USER_ID,
          "app_id": APP_ID
      },
      "inputs": [
          {
              "data": {
                  "image": {
                      "url": this.state.IMAGE_URL
                  }
              }
          }
      ]
  });

  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Key ' + PAT
      },
      body: raw
  };

  // NOTE: MODEL_VERSION_ID is optional, you can also call prediction with the MODEL_ID only
  // https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/{YOUR_MODEL_ID}/outputs
  // this will default to the latest version_id

  fetch("https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" + MODEL_ID + "/versions/" + MODEL_VERSION_ID + "/outputs", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```

I started facing this issue when I  added IMAGE_URL in constructor to update it from my input form on the webpage.
It works fine if i move IMAGE_URL out from the constructor and making it a variable and hard code the image url in the editor

Edit:
This is the code after some tweaks. Still same error

```
onInputChange = (event) =>{
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
    console.log(typeof(input),'TYPE OF INPUT');
    var inp = this.state.input;
    return inp
     //console.log(inp);
     console.log(typeof(inp)); //it is string here
  }

  onSubmit = () =>{
    this.setState({IMAGE_URL : this.state.inp});
    
    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      "user_app_id": {
          "user_id": USER_ID,
          "app_id": APP_ID
      },
      "inputs": [
          {
              "data": {
                  "image": {
                      "url": this.state.IMAGE_URL
                  }
              }
          }
      ]
```

Edit 2:
It's working now and I guess I broke some rules. I have declared a global variable and passed the value of the input field to it and then used it in my API.

```
var inp = ''; //THIS IS THE NEW VARIABLE
class App extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      input : '',
      IMAGE_URL: '',
    }
  }
  onInputChange = (event) =>{
    this.setState({input: event.target.value}); 
    
    
    
    inp = event.target.value;
    console.log(inp);
    return inp;
   
  }

  onSubmit = () =>{
    console.log('*********',inp,'***********');
    this.setState({IMAGE_URL : this.state.input});
    
    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      "user_app_id": {
          "user_id": USER_ID,
          "app_id": APP_ID
      },
      "inputs": [
          {
              "data": {
                  "image": {
                      "url": inp
                  }
              }
          }
      ]
```

Comment: Can you do a console.log of both the `raw` variable when you're using it hard coded vs. dynamic?  The only thing I am seeing is that maybe the type isn't the same (i.e. string) and its causing the `raw` string to encode as something different.

Comment: @syntheticgio raw variable with dynamic input {"user_app_id":{"user_id":"kkf1d032jwpm","app_id":"my-first-application"},"inputs":[{"data":{"image":{}}}]}

Comment: raw variable with hard coded input   {"user_app_id":{"user_id":"kkf1d032jwpm","app_id":"my-first-application"},"inputs":[{"data":{"image":{"url":"https://i0.wp.com/post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/03/GettyImages-1092658864_hero-1024x575.jpg?w=1155&h=1528"}}}]}

Comment: @syntheticgio you were right. I console.log typeof IMAGE_URL in dynamic one and it was undefined and i managed to convert it into string by storing it in another variable. However, it seems to be just disappearing when i use it as url in API. I am completely lost

Comment: Added a comment that I think explains what is going on; sorry for the delay in the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've found a workaround with a global variable; but I think the actual problem was with:

`this.setState({IMAGE_URL : this.state.input});`

in the `onSubmit` function.

The setState function in react:

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

So basically you're making a request to update that variable (IMAGE_URL) and then immediately using it.  Since React is trying to optimize writes, you are trying to use it *before* it is actually updated.  You can request that update and then use the already populated version if you want.

I think the following code should work and allow you to keep out of the global scope (if that bothers you).

```js
class App extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      input : '',
      IMAGE_URL: '',
    }
  }
  onInputChange = (event) =>{
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  onSubmit = () =>{

    // This may not trigger right away, but if you want to transfer the this.state.input to this.state.IMAGE_URL it _eventually_ will
    this.setState({IMAGE_URL : this.state.input});

    const raw = JSON.stringify({
      "user_app_id": {
          "user_id": USER_ID,
          "app_id": APP_ID
      },
      "inputs": [
          {
              "data": {
                  "image": {
                      "url": this.state.input
                  }
              }
          }
      ]
  });

  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Key ' + PAT
      },
      body: raw
  };

  // NOTE: MODEL_VERSION_ID is optional, you can also call prediction with the MODEL_ID only
  // https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/{YOUR_MODEL_ID}/outputs
  // this will default to the latest version_id

  fetch("https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" + MODEL_ID + "/versions/" + MODEL_VERSION_ID + "/outputs", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```